# Safari CSP ignores nonce and unsafe-inline

Tags: safari, content-security-policy

I'm in the process of locking down our CSP further and applying a CSP3 nonce based approach. Everything works fine in all browsers except Safari:

An example inline script with a nonce and the following CSP (trimmed to remove some URLs we allow - I've checked the Nonce matches too):

```
content-security-policy-report-only: script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https: 'strict-dynamic' 'nonce-xxxx'; upgrade-insecure-requests; default-src 'self' gap: blob:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; base-uri 'none'; report-uri https://xxx.report-uri.com/r/d/csp/reportOnly
```

Safari's Error:
[image: Safari error]

I'm testing on Safari 11 on OSx but the issue is present on Safari 12 according to our test reporting.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I solved this:

In my experience and from testing here: You can't have an enforced and a report only CSP at the same time with Safari, it seems to mix policies up between them and report violations for non violating items.

Remove one of the CSP directives and either send a Report only or an enforced and it'll start working as intended.

Edit (16th March 2022) : Safari now fails to load completely if you have both a read only and an enforced CSP policy. The webkit bug has remained completely idle since this was first logged so we've had to remove the read only CSP to get Safari to work at all.

If anyone has contact at Webkit I'd really appreciate someone shining a light on this to try and get Webkit to actually work like a browser instead of the new IE6 again.

Comment: It looks like maybe there’s already an open bug for this at https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=158103. Does that seem like the same problem you ran into?